# How to trigger download with Rails send_data from AJAX post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, canvas

I'm trying to use `send_data` to return a PNG image as the response for a ajax post request. How do I get the browser to trigger a download on the success callback?

#### Details

I'm generating a large base64 image using `canvas.toDataURL()`, and then posting it to Rails (v3.2.6). Rails decodes it to a binary PNG, and sends the image back to the client.

I've also tried `send_file` but it has the same issue.

#### Other options

1. **Download image client side:** We can't do this because (1) [Safari crashes on large base64 URLs](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112053), and (2) [Safari does not yet support the download attribute on anchor tags](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) which I would need to specify the downloaded image filename.
2. **Use a `$.get` instead of `$.post`:** We can't do this because we need to send our `canvas.toDataURL()` with the request to the server. `GET` requests URIs have size limitations.

Comment: Well then put the data from the AJAX request into the session, and then trigger the download by `location.href="..."` pointing to a script that sends the appropriate headers, passes the data from the session and afterwards deletes it from the session.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use an AJAX request to download a file.  A non-AJAX link_to that reverences a send_data/send_file action should download the image.

Comment: I think it is a http standard about how to download data as file. maybe use content_type: 'image/png' ?

Comment: I had to do the same type of thing and ended up just decoding and saving the image server side, then using window.open in javascript to open a window that used send_file from the server to get the image, then just remove the temp image on the server.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

create a function in controller

```
def ajax_download
  send_file "path_to_file/" + params[:file]
end
```

and then in controller action

```
respond_to do |format|
  @java_url = "/home/ajax_download?file=#{file_name}"
  format.js {render :partial => "downloadFile"}
end
```

and make a partial in view folder name with _downloadFile.js.erb and write this line

```
window.location.href = "<%=@java_url %>"
```

Comment: You might want to make an iframe and set it's location to the URL of the file. Either way, this is a solid solution.

Comment: @mayatron Please approve this one

Comment: Worked here for me :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that using `params[:file]` in `send_file` is unsanitized, and could lead to data theft.

Answer (score 3):

You can't download a file to disk from JS. It's a security concern.  See the blog post below for a good workaround.

http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx

Comment: You can download canvas images as base64, as long as the image isn't tainted. There are some limitations with this, for example setting the filename. Working example: http://greenethumb.com/article/1429/user-friendly-image-saving-from-the-canvas/

Answer (score 2):

Do **not** just copy and paste the accepted answer. It is a massive security risk that cannot be understated. Although the technique is clever, delivering a file based on a parameter anybody can enter allows access to any file anybody can imagine is lying around.

Here's an example of a more secure way to use the same technique. It assumes there is a user logged in who has an API token, but you should be able to adapt it to your own scenario.

In the action:

```
current_user.pending_download = file_name
current_user.save!
respond_to do |format|
  @java_url = "/ajax_download?token=#{current_user.api_token}"
  format.js {render :partial => "downloadFile"}
end
```

Create a function in the controller

```
def ajax_download
  if params[:token] == current_user.api_token
    send_file "path_to_file/" + current_user.pending_download
    current_user.pending_download = ''
    current_user.save!
  else
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Unauthorized"
  end
end
```

Make a partial in view folder name with _downloadFile.js.erb

```
window.location.href = "<%=@java_url %>"
```

And of course you will need a route that points to `/ajax_download` in `routes.rb`

```
get 'ajax_download', to: 'controller#ajax_download'
```