# Is it possible to use send_data (not send_file) via ajax request in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a link that downloads a dynamically generated file.  The way I have it functioning is the following:

- I created a custom controller action on a resource (created a custom route in `routes.rb`)
- Clicking the link (non-ajax at this point) directs to this custom Controller action
- The file is generated, and the last line in the custom controller action is `send_data` which streams the document to the user.

**Update**: It was recommended to include code.  Here is the code in that custom controller action:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def custom_action_sending_pdf
    pdf = InitMyPdf.new(@user)
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "complete_report.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
  end
end
```

The issue is that `request.referrer` for the ***next*** request will now reference *this* custom controller action, and I do not want it to do that.  This is also reflected in the url.

- This specifically becomes an issue when later in my app I redirect back to `request.referrer`. When the `request.referrer` is this custom controller action: it does not redirect to an actual page but instead just re-downloads the document all over again.

Instead I try this:

- I make the link to that custom action an *ajax* request via the `remote: true` option

On one hand: the `request.referrer` now properly seems to not be referencing that controller action.  However, now the file is not downloading!

I have done some looking around:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699113/rails-how-do-i-export-data-with-send-data-then-redirect-to-a-new-page) does not have an answer that can be immediately applied.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242359/how-to-trigger-download-with-rails-send-data-from-ajax-post) applies to downloading a static file which does not work for me because my file is dynamically generated, so I use `send_data` to send the generated file to the user as opposed to `send_file`.

**Question:** Ultimately I am trying to let a user download a dynamically generated file, all while NOT changing the page (keeping the `request.referrer` the same).  Is this possible?

**Update**
I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951296/is-it-possible-to-use-send-data-via-ajax-request-in-rails?noredirect=1#comment84911144_48951296) but the issue with it is that it's accepted answer is using `send_file`, and since my file is dynamically generated: `send_file` will not work for me here.

Comment: So that I can be more specific, whoever voted that this question be closed: please explain where the ambiguity is in my question that warrants it being closed.  I will try to be more clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger download with Rails send\_data from AJAX post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242359/how-to-trigger-download-with-rails-send-data-from-ajax-post)

Comment: @Rob the accepted answer in that question is using `send_file` and I mention in my question that `send_file` is not a usable solution for me.

Comment: I think you wouldn't get so many close votes if you included your code in the question. I think the question is clear enough, but I think it's kind of a kneejerk reaction of answerers to vote to close a question whenn it has a bunch of text describibng code and no code block. Annyway, just to give my quick 2 cents, I would consider 2 options: 1, manually change request.referrer in the controller action, if that's possible. 2, create a tempfile with the dynamically generated content and send that over with `send_file`

Comment: @maxpleaner thanks for your input.  I added what applicable code I could.  I didn't add it before because I wasn't really getting an "error" due to my code.  I understand why it is behaving as it is.  I just do not know how to go about getting the desired behavior. Your suggestion of creating a file and using `send_file` as described by the other questions is a good recommendation.  I will look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works.  use [button_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

Example:

```
<%= button_to(<custom_action_sending_pdf_path>, method: :get, class: 'btn btn-primary') do %>
  <i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i></i> Print PDF
<% end %>
```

Let that button go to that custom action which downloads the pdf (same code as in original question):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def custom_action_sending_pdf
    pdf = InitMyPdf.new(@user)
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "complete_report.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
  end
end
```

What happens now is when that button is clicked:

- The pdf downloads and pops up adobe (at least it does this in safari)
- The url of the page *does not* change to the custom action which prints the pdf.  So for the next request: `request.referrer` will not be that custom action for the pdf, which is the desired behavior here.